# Use Regex to fetch data

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex I have made fetches itemlist from **opts.taskDetails.order_details**.

[image]

I want to optimize the regex/any other better regex to get the following data as is shown in the above image. 
(which can be 1 item list or multiple).

Also apart from fetching the item details I also want to fetch data which is left after fetching items list from **opts.taskDetails.order_details** below.

```
Tipo de papa: -\nPapa Amarilla Tumbay S/0.00\n Adicional : - Quesp cheddar S/0.00\n Agrega Bebida: - Fanta 400 ml S/0.00\n
Salsas: - Mayonesa S/0.00\n - Ketchup S/0.00\n - Golf S/0.00\n - Guacamole S/0.00\n - Ají S/0.00\n - Tártara S/0.00\n - Mayo-aji S/0.00\n
```

**CODE**

```js
var opts = {
      "items": [{
        "mail_parser_label": "order_details",
        "label": "order_details",
        "data_type": "Table",
        "app_side": "0",
        "required": 0,
        "value": 1,
        "data": {
          "head": [{
            "mail_parser_label": "Detalle",
            "label": "Detalle",
            "type": "text",
            "arth": " ",
            "id": 0,
            "show": 1,
            "app_side": 0,
            "required": 0
          }, {
            "mail_parser_label": "Cantidad",
            "label": "Cantidad",
            "type": "text",
            "arth": " ",
            "id": 1,
            "show": 1,
            "app_side": 0,
            "required": 0
          }, {
            "mail_parser_label": "Unidad",
            "label": "Unidad",
            "type": "text",
            "arth": " ",
            "id": 2,
            "show": 1,
            "app_side": 0,
            "required": 0
          }, {
            "mail_parser_label": "Total",
            "label": "Total",
            "type": "text",
            "arth": " ",
            "id": 2,
            "show": 1,
            "app_side": 0,
            "required": 0
          }],
          "other": [],
          "body": []
        },
        "template_id": "NUEVO_PEDIDO",
        "appCheck": true
      }],
      "taskDetails": {
      "order_details":"Detalle\n Unidad\n Cantidad\n Total\n     Triple Insomnio Especial   S/37.90 1  S/37.90   Insomnio Especial  \nS/212 S/23.12 *Tipo de papa:*  - Papa Amarilla Tumbay S/0.00\n     *Adicional :*  - Quesp cheddar S/0.00\n     *Agrega Bebida:*  - Fanta 400 ml S/0.00\n     *Salsas:*  - Mayonesa S/0.00\n - Ketchup S/0.00\n - Golf S/0.00\n - Guacamole S/0.00\n - Ají S/0.00\n - Tártara S/0.00\n - Mayo-aji S/0.00\n       "
      
    }
}
    
    var items = opts.items;
    var taskDetails = opts.taskDetails;
    for (var p = 0; p < items.length; p++) {
      var parameter = items[p];
      if (parameter.mail_parser_label == "order_details") {
        var str = taskDetails.order_details.toString().replace(/[ ]+/g, ' ');
        var itemPatternFull = str.match(/[A-Za-z0-9 ]*S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g);
        var itemPattern = itemPatternFull ? itemPatternFull.toString().match(/S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g) : [];
        var details = itemPatternFull ? itemPatternFull.toString().replace(/S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g, '').toString().split(',') : [];
        var itemPatternLength = str.match(/S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g).length;
        var itemPattern = str.match(/S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g);
        var itemPatternArray = itemPattern.toString().replace(',', ' ').split(' ');
        str = str.split(' ');
    
    
    
        var count = 0;
        if (itemPatternArray.length < str.length && details.length == itemPatternArray.length / 3) {
          for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < itemPatternArray.length; columnIndex++) {
            if (columnIndex % 3 == 0) {
              parameter.data.body.push({
                "val": details[count].trim(),
                "id": count + columnIndex,
                "head": "Dettalle"
              });
              count++;
            }
            parameter.data.body.push({
              "val": itemPatternArray[columnIndex].replace(/S\//, ''),
              "id": columnIndex + count,
              "head": str[(columnIndex % 3) + 1] ? str[(columnIndex % 3) + 1].toString().replace('\n', '') : str[(columnIndex % 3) + 1]
            });
          }
        }
      } else {
        parameter.data = taskDetails[parameter.mail_parser_label].toString().trim().replace(/[\s+\n]/g, ' ');
      }
    }
    console.log("ITEMS", parameter.data.body)
```

Comment: _"But it is not woeking as expected"_ - Please be more specific on what is happening, what should happen instead, if there are any errors in the console, what the output is and what it should look like instead.

Comment: Your RegEx will equate to `"S/37.90 1  S/37.90"` [(seen here)](https://regex101.com/r/m1cAWH/5) therefore `item = ["S/37.90","1","","S/37.90"]` so `item.slice(0, i-1).join(' ') = "S/37.90 1"` and `item[i] = "S/37.90"`... They shouldn't present you any issues here, could the `qty[count]` be out of bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `regex` to chop up your `order_details` and also extract the remainder at the end.

I used one rx to get header, items, and extras.  Then another to parse the items using the `g` flag.  You can validate even more, either in the regex, or parsing the match into a number, but you should get the point.  The key is 2 phase parsing.

I put the results in an `order` object.  You can simply map that to whatever you want; It was easier to show the regex and solution isolated from your other code.

```js
var order_details = `Detalle\n Unidad\n Cantidad\n Total\n Triple Insomnio Especial S/37.90 1 S/37.90 Insomnio Especial \nS/23.12 1 S/23.12 Tipo de papa: - Papa Amarilla Tumbay S/0.00\n Adicional : - Quesp cheddar S/0.00\n Agrega Bebida: - Fanta 400 ml S/0.00\n Salsas: - Mayonesa S/0.00\n - Ketchup S/0.00\n - Golf S/0.00\n - Guacamole S/0.00\n - Ají S/0.00\n - Tártara S/0.00\n - Mayo-aji S/0.00\n " `

var order_details2 = `Detalle\n Unidad\n Cantidad\n Total\n Combo Cheese Burger para 2 S/39.90 1 S/39.90 Salsas primera: -\nGolf S/0.00\n Elige tu bebida: - Coca Cola 500ml S/0.00\n Elige tu bebida: - Coca Cola 500ml S/0.00\n Verduras primera : - Cebolla blanca S/0.00\n - Tomate S/0.00\n - Lechuga S/0.00\n Salsas segunda : - Golf S/0.00\n - Tártara S/0.00\n Verduras segunda : - Cebolla blanca S/0.00\n - Tomate S/0.00\n - Lechuga S/0.00\n Porción de papa : - Papa Regular S/0.00\n`

function parse(string) {
  // header, items, and tipo
  var rxItems = /Detalle\n Unidad\n Cantidad\n\ Total\n\s*([^:]+)(([^:]+:[\s\S]*)) /

  // single item line
  var rxItem = /s*(.*?)\s+(S\/.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(S\/.*?)/g

  var order = {
    items: [],
    other: null
  }

  var mParts = rxItems.exec(string)
  var items = mParts[1]
  order.other = mParts[2]

  var mItem = rxItem.exec(items)
  while (mItem) {
    var detalle = mItem[1]
    var unidad = mItem[2]
    var cantidad = mItem[3]
    var total = mItem[4]
    let item = {
      detalle,
      unidad,
      cantidad,
      total
    }
    order.items.push(item)
    mItem = rxItem.exec(items)
  }
  console.log(order)
}

parse(order_details)
parse(order_details2)
```

Comment: just edited the code for multiple items @Steven Spungin

Comment: your code is not working for multiple item list @Steven Spungin

Comment: @art You need to specify how `order_details` will be formatted for multiple items.  That's the unknown here.

Comment: I edited my question please check @ Steven Spungin

 "order_details":"Detalle\n Unidad\n Cantidad\n Total\n     Triple Insomnio Especial   S/37.90 1  S/37.90   Insomnio Especial  \nS/212 S/23.12 *Tipo de papa:*  - Papa Amarilla Tumbay S/0.00\n     *Adicional :*  - Quesp cheddar S/0.00\n     *Agrega Bebida:*  - Fanta 400 ml S/0.00\n     *Salsas:*  - Mayonesa S/0.00\n - Ketchup S/0.00\n - Golf S/0.00\n - Guacamole S/0.00\n - Ají S/0.00\n - Tártara S/0.00\n - Mayo-aji S/0.00\n       "

Comment: @art I updated.  It looks like your `Insomnio Especial` was not formated correctly though (item quantity total) so I fixed it.

Comment: You took a static header (Tipo de papa:[\s\S]*)  , whereas it is dynamic
@Steven Spungin

Comment: var order_details =  Detalle\n Unidad\n Cantidad\n Total\n     Combo Cheese Burger para 2  S/39.90 1  S/39.90    *Salsas primera:*  -\nGolf S/0.00\n     *Elige tu bebida:*  - Coca Cola 500ml S/0.00\n     *Elige tu bebida:*  - Coca Cola 500ml S/0.00\n     *Verduras primera :*  - Cebolla blanca S/0.00\n - Tomate S/0.00\n - Lechuga S/0.00\n     *Salsas segunda :*  - Golf S/0.00\n - Tártara S/0.00\n     *Verduras segunda :*  - Cebolla blanca S/0.00\n - Tomate S/0.00\n - Lechuga S/0.00\n     *Porción de papa :*  - Papa Regular S/0.00\n

Comment: @art Come on now Art, how are we to know what is static and what is dynamic given your posted data set?...

Comment: Only this part is left rest your answer is correct @Steven Spungin

Comment: What part is left?

Comment: @art OK. As long as there are no ':' in the items, my solution will work.  Otherwise you will have to scan by lines, and use a modulus for columns.

Comment: So is your last updated solution complete? I guess you were doing with modulus
@Steven Spungin

Comment: No, I stuck to regex as the original question asked.  Using the colon allows us to find the 'extras' part.

Comment: Thanks for your solution I am accepting your solution @Steven Spungin